# Remove extra edge from BST

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a BST which looks like below. How can I remove extra edge not needed from BST?

1->2, 1->3, 2->4, 2->5, 3->5

Should remove either 2->5 or 3->5

```
 void BFS(int s)
    {
        // Mark all the vertices as not visited(By default
        // set as false)
        boolean visited[] = new boolean[V];

        // Create a queue for BFS
        LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        // Mark the current node as visited and enqueue it
        visited[s]=true;
        queue.add(s);

        while (queue.size() != 0)
        {
            // Dequeue a vertex from queue and print it
            s = queue.poll();
            System.out.print(s+" ");

            // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued vertex s
            // If a adjacent has not been visited, then mark it
            // visited and enqueue it
            Iterator<Integer> i = adj[s].listIterator();
            while (i.hasNext())
            {
                int n = i.next();
                if (!visited[n])
                {
                    visited[n] = true;
                    queue.add(n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

What you have is not a tree, it's a *Directed Acyclic Graph* (DAG):

[image: DAG]

The algorithm you are looking for is a [*Spanning Tree Algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree). One of the simplest ways to find it is to run through your graph depth-first, and mark graph nodes as you find them. If an edge takes you to a node that you have already seen, remove the edge and continue. Once you are done with the depth-first walk, the remaining graph is a tree.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to implement is a self balancing binary tree.  An AVL tree is one such.  The [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) has some well commented pseudo code which should't be terribly difficult to implement in Java.

A web search will reveal plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
// **Assuming we are maintaining a isVisited flag inside tree node. We can implement this in separate array but for simplicity I assumed it to be inside the node.**

boolean removeBadEdge(Node root) {
    if (root == null)
        return false;
    if (root.left != null && root.left.isVisited)
    {
        root.left = null; // Removing the bad edge
        return true;
    }
    if (root.right!= null && root.right.isVisited)
    {
        root.right= null; // Removing the bad edge
        return true;
    }

    root.isVisited = true;    

   boolean leftEdgeRemoved = removeBadEdge(root.left);
   boolean rightEdgeRemoved = false;
   if (!leftEdgeRemoved) { // call right only if not removed in left for optimization
       rightEdgeRemoved  = removeBadEdge(root.right);
   }

   return leftEdgeRemoved || rightEdgeRemoved;
}
```

Comment: This will not work in the edge case below, where child node is same (here left and right child of A is B node):

  A
/    \
\    /
  B

Also this will not work in the case where root loops to itself (here A root node loops to itself):

  A
 /
A

it will require small fixes